# Counter for Korean War Wagon

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I have been playing Age of Empires - Conquerors for more than 6 years. We used to compete each other using LAN. What we generally experience is, with population limit of 100 or more, the Korean war wagon seems to be indestructible because of its large hit point and good attack. What would be a good strategy to defeat it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the simple answer is

Get in close to nullify the war wagon's range attack advantage. Like all cavalry units, it is susceptible to pikemen, skirmishers and camels.

[Here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5871538_defeat-war-wagon-age-empires.html) are some more tips, but it basically comes down to the same point

Answer (score 10):

Pikemen are especially effective if they manage to get close. A practical approach though, is to use cavalry - especially light cavalry which are somewhat less susceptible to missile damage. Cavalry can close in fast and quite effective in groups.

Massed war wagon are pretty hard to beat and will take down much of your pikemen or cavalry before they get close. One alternative approach that I've seen used (but never used myself) is to use a small group of onagers. The onagers are kept behind other units for protection so they don't get attacked right away, and they all attack at once once they get in range. This only works if they are fully upgraded, and even then this is basically a sacrificial strategy, you you will end up losing your onagers to the war wagons that survive the initial attack. But it does destroy a number of war wagons and weaken the others, and give a better chance for other units to close in.

Comment: Any onager strategy needs to take into account the fact that Koreans are one of the top siege onager civs in the game.

Answer (score 2):

if possible use cavalry men, that is the best way to finish off a war wagon..

Answer (score 2):

Use mass Skirmishers, preferably with Onagers behind them. If required, some Light Cavalry can also be expended to soften them up. I feel this is the best approach keeping in mind the costs involved and the fact that any civilization can implement this counter..

Keep in mind that you will lose quite a few units, but I have used this several times, and think it works best. Skirmishers are easily replaceable. And since War Wagons are basically (very) beefed up Cavalry Archers, you get a neat bonus while attacking them

Answer (score 1):

I think Turk is the best civilization versus Koreans especially on the Black Forest map.  When your rival has Koreans war wagon (range 9) with Onagers (range 12) behind them. Turks bombard toward (range 13), bombard cannon (range 14) and some Janissary (range 8) can be most effective.

Answer (score 0):

Use Huskarls.  They are infantry and are the Gothic unique unit.

Answer (score 0):

Warwagons are extremely powerful. As a matter of fact, the Korean civilization used to get banned in LAN plays/leagues when Age of Empires was a hit back in my days.

I've countered them with Camels; its the best way, and don't forget that Korean units can be converted/do not die, so conversion along with camels is best way to get them.

But strategically the best way I defeated them was using Chinese/Mayans/Britains. Not due to archers or damage, but a fast game where I attack the Koreans before they hit the Castle Age, and keep them under pressure all the time by capturing much of their resource points.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but Hussars are the best to beat war wagons when they are massed.   If there are just a few pikeman in mass will go through them quickly and as far as a mathematical advantage - especially the civs like Japan that have bonuses.   The problem with pikeman is that a good user will just need a few swordsman/whatever-infantry in front of wagons and while the pikeman are swinging away at them every mass reload is two dead pikeman with no damage to mass.

But the Hussars secret is that the AI for their attack is just so dumb that the opponents war wagons will be all over the place chasing the hussars.   I take a group of 30 hussars vs 20-30 war wagons and put them barely out of range then roam and do their thing.   They chase everything and are very hard for the war wagons to hit unless it is head on.   Yea they will die, but the war wagons will be all over the place and by the time those 30 hussars are dead 30 more will pop out and start pegging the wagons 1 at a time.   I have seen wagons across the map chasing a hussar around.   Jus the lack of intelligence of hussars make them perfect to break up any kind of mass attack.   Obviously Turk, Spanish, or Hun civilization helps.